# Print Resharper Live Templates

Tags: visual-studio, templates, resharper

In there any way to print a list of all my templates in Resharper.

Recently, I installed the mnemonics plugin which have added a lot of templates and I'm lost in all these shortcuts.

It would be nice to have a pretty print list with every template shortcut, the description and a sample of the code. This will surely help me using more template then now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly something you can print out, but I have a little project that can round trip Live Templates between `.dotSettings` and `.md` files. It can also generate a nice `README.md` that lists all of the templates, gives the description, and provides a link to the `.md` version of the template file.

You can see the mnemonics templates here: [README.md](https://github.com/citizenmatt/resharper-template-compiler/blob/master/samples/mnemonics/README.md)

Comment: It's not perfect but It surely do the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My answer concerns Mnemonics extention. There is [no official print-friendly keymap](https://github.com/JetBrains/mnemonics/issues/10) yet. Fortunately, large set of mnemonics is based on few common principles (so I just printed main page to remember it). Of course, you can investigate each mnemonic in ReSharper Templates Explorer.